# Expiring Logged In User's Session After Set Time in Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

When a user logs into my Laravel app, I'd like them to have two options:

1. If "remember me" checkbox isn't checked, have session expire at browser close
2. If "remember me" is checked, have session expire after 10 minutes of inactivity

I implement user login with the following:

```
Auth::attempt($userData, Input::has('remember'));
```

and in my `session.php` file, I have

```
'lifetime' => 10,
'expire_on_close' => true
```

If the "remember me" checkbox isn't checked, my user is logged out as expected when the browser closes.  If it is checked, the user stays logged in indefinitely.  I am under the assumption that with the above config, the user should be logged out after 10 minutes of inactivity.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of cookies:

> **Persistent Cookies**: that are stored until you remove them manually or they expire
>
> **Session Cookies**: that are stored until your close your browser

The `lifetime` setting will create a persistent cookie with the expiration date set `10` minutes into the future according to the value. The `expire_on_close` setting will create a session cookie.

Because you **can't have two cookies** named `laravel_session`, the session cookie trumps the persistent one. So when the `expires_on close` is set to `true` you only get a session cookie that gets used until the browser is closed, and the `lifetime` setting is ignored.

---

The **"Remember Me"** option is something separate and is used to persist the authenticated user. It does not use any of the two session settings described above, because it creates it's own cookie with an expiration date that is set to 5 years and will only get removed when you call `Auth::logout()`. So it does not matter if the `laravel_session` cookie is removed, the authenticated user is restored via the remember cookie.

---

So as far as your scenarios go with your current session config here's what happens:

1. If **"remember me"** isn't checked, the user session will expire when to browser closes (the lifetime is useless)
2. If **"remember me"** is checked the user session will only expire in 5 years or if your remove the remember cookie or logout the user (the settings in `config/session.php` have no effect on the user session when the user is "remembered").

So what you want is not possible with the standard Laravel authentication system.

Comment: Wasn't really looking for a description of persistent vs session cookies; rather I am looking at how to achieve the desired effects I described within Laravel.

Comment: I understand, and in the last paragraph I explained that you can't, at least not using the native way Laravel handles session cookies, because once you set `expires_on_close` to true `lifetime` is ignored. The remember me part is not a factor here, regardless if it's true or false, because that is a different cookie that will keep the authentication session data alive regardless of the other cookies. The cookies preamble was there to avoid misunderstandings about what the settings represent :).

Comment: What's the point of having a remember me option then (second parameter on the `attempt()` method)?  Is it only relevant when `expire_on_close` is set to `false` and only persistent cookies are being generated?

Comment: The `laravel_session` cookie that gets created to handle all session data is one cookie used in this case. By passing `true` as the second parameter to the `attempt` method, a second cookie is created named `rememeber_[some_hash_string]` which contains the **authenticated user** data, which is used to "revive" the auth session with the necessary user info. So when **remember me** is true, if the `laravel_session` cookie gets removed it does not affect authentication, you only loose other data set with `session()->set('data', 'value')`, `auth()->user()` will still return the user.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the relevant explanation about the remember option.